# Desktop application - How to store Data for multiple boots

Tags: java, database, spring

first of all I know that there are some questions here which have a similar title but the use case were always different.

I have a desktop application (Windows/Linux environment), written in Java with Spring boot. Executed as a .jar

I want that this application can be closed and restarted and the previous stored/used data is still available. But the requirement is that user doesn't need to install a Database seperately. I tested the embedded H2 Database feature of Spring but at every reboot of the application it is empty. It appears this solution is only appropriate for the runtime?

The one and only solution I figured out is to use an objectwrite and store the data in XML and re-read it after a restard. But many say that this is not the professional way to go for storing data.

So is there any solution beside XML or is it just not possible without installing an external DB?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use H2 database with `file` to persist the data into the file, this way, there won't be any need to install the database separately, have a look at the different H2 configutations [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html).

application.propertiles will look like these:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/data
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Also, you can use `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` to stop the database from closing when VM exists, as explained [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#do_not_close_on_exit). So, the db url would be:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/data;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Comment: An extra thank you for that transparent and complete Solution!